# how to verify a user from two different tables using single java service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an Admin table and Customer Table, using single java service I want to validate Both?

using below service I can only validate admin, but the UI person would send me whatever object he wants(admin or customer for login validation),so in the same service I have to check that it is Admin or Customer and then validate. 
Could you please help me to overcome the issue, please...

```
String userName="AdminName";
String passWord="AdminPassword";
Query query =getSession().createQuery("from Admin where 
adminUsername="+userName);
Admin admin=query.uniqueResult();   
if (passWord.equals(admin.getAdminPassword)) {
    return "login Success";
else "failed";
```

Comment: Among other things: (1) Use JPA instead of legacy Hibernate APIs. (2) Use a generic query method. (3) You're missing `SELECT`. (4) You don't need to write any of the code anyway if you use Spring Data JPA. (5) You should be hashing your passwords. (6) Return `true` or `false`, not magic strings. (7) Close your braces. (8) Don't do any of this anyway and let Spring Security do it, because it's tested and verified.

Comment: have you tried using "union", you can make a union of both the tables and check.